# Ignoring files with wildcard in name

Tags: gitignore

I want to ignore files with a certain name but allow any version. 
example: I want to ignore all baz-* files without needing to point out every version. Is it possible with gitignore?

foo.jar
bar.jar
baz-1.0.1.jar
baz-2.0.0.jar
baz-2.1.0.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use wildcard, just add `baz*` to `.gitignore` to ignore file names start with baz.